# ClosedXML Changing Number Formats

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am doing the following in ClosedXML (standard accounting format for numbers):

```
ws.Column(col).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* \" - \"??_);_(@_)";
```

When the output renders, it doesn't look like what I specified.  If I inspect the format, it has been changed to this:

```
[$$-en-US]#,##0.00_);([$$-en-US]#,##0.00)
```

Close, and passable, but not what I input.

Anyone know what gives?  Is this ClosedXml or is it Excel?  I can do it manually in Excel, and it works perfectly.

Comment: That's some rather unconventional format string there. Anyways, what is your expected output? Which ClosedXML version are you running? What happened to the zero and text format, did it get lost? Please precizise your question.

Comment: That's the default currency format when you click the "$" button on the ribbon.  It yields that as a custom format string which puts padding between the currency sign and the value, puts a '-' in when the value is 0, puts parentheses when it's negative.  My expected result is that it would keep a format string I specify!  I'm unclear why it changed it.  I am on the latest version of ClosedXML (0.95.4)

Comment: Oh I see, my Excel localization doesn't have that format for currency with parentheses, weird. But I found it having the `[$$-en-US]` as currency symbol and updating format strings on opening a file.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Excel is doing some magic on opening a file, propably for localization compatibility. Also on editing the cell format some sort of 'assistance' happens.

Following code should work for you or at least point you in the right direction:

```
ws.Column(col).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "_([$$-en-US]_(#,##0.00_);_([$$-en-US]_((#,##0.00)_);_(-_);_(@_)";
```

Please note that on editing the format afterwards in Excel it will likely 'assist' you again and propably mess up. You will find the original format string under 'Userdefined', tho.

Help on format strings is also [provided by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68).